# avoid opening new window when downloading s3 object

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3

[download code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgdi4.png)

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import FaDownload from "react-icons/lib/fa/download";
import { Auth, API, Storage } from "aws-amplify";


class DownloadCell extends PureComponent {
  onclick = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      const stored = await Storage.get(this.props.node.data.Key.split('/')[1])
      window.open(stored)

    } catch (error) {      
      console.error("S3 download error: ", error);
    }
  };
```

trying to use AWS amplify to download s3 bucket files, not sure how to implement it correctly so the file does not end up in new window.

Comment: Where do you want the file to be?

Answer (score -1):

just remove the window.open()

```
onclick = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      const stored = await Storage.get(this.props.node.data.Key.split('/')[1])
      //whatever you want with the stored
      //.....

    } catch (error) {      
      console.error("S3 download error: ", error);
    }
```

Comment: Pretty sure the answer is this part: `//whatever you want with the stored`. Seems like that could be more complete...